# php link with multiple variables with the same value

Tags: php, sql

The code is for the site docuindex.net

i need to add multiple categories for one documentary, and i'm not sure how to do that. So for ex when you click on the Nature category you will see the x docu, and also if you click on the science category you will see the x docu if it belongs to both of them

```
<?php 
$subQ = ''; 
if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat']!=''){
$subQ = ' WHERE Category="'.mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat'])).'"';}   
if(isset($_GET['cat2']) && $_GET['cat2']!=''){
$subQ = ' WHERE Category2="'.mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat2'])).'"';} 
?>


<a href="?cat=nature">Nature</a> 
<a href="?cat2=science">Science</a>
```

that should be something like

```
<a href="?cat=nature or cat2=nature">Nature</a> 

<a href="?cat=scinece or cat2=science">Science</a>
```

If anyone could help that would be great

THANK YOU EVERYONE especially Sam Sullivan ! the thing that was missing was : 
`<a href="?cat=scinece&cat2=science">Science</a>` and do this for every category `<a href="?cat=nature&cat2=nature">Nature</a>` etc etc (in the main post i wrote OR insted of AND). This way i can add multiple main categories and subcategories to the same documentary.

Comment: Use `&` to add multiple params to the URL: `?cat=nature&cat2=nature`.

Comment: OP is asking 'how do I let someone click the science button (to retrieve all documentaries with tag science) then if they click the nature button it will add that to further filter the documentaries (so filter by science AND nature now)? Am I right user3170452?

Comment: Nope, Sam Sullivan gave me the help i needed, the thing that was missing was : <a href="?cat=scinece&cat2=science">Science</a> and do this for every category <a href="?cat=nature&cat2=nature">Nature</a> etc etc (in the main post i wrote OR insted of AND). This way i can add multiple main categories and subcategories to the same documentary. Thank you every one for the input !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, but I think you are looking for MySQL's `OR`.

```
<?php 
$subQ = 'WHERE';

if(!empty($_GET['cat'])) {
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat']));
    $subQ .= " Category='category' OR";
}

if(!empty($_GET['cat2'])) {
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat2']));
    $subQ .= " Category='category' OR";
}

if($subQ == 'WHERE') $subQ = '';
$subQ = substr($subQ, 0, -3); // remove trailing OR
?>

<a href="?cat=nature&cat2=science">Nature OR Science</a>
```

If you want this to be Nature **and** Science, you can set the `OR`s to `AND`s and modify the final function to `substr($subQ, 0, -4);` to remove the extra character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $subQ = ''; 
    if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat']!='')
         $subQ = ' WHERE Category="'.mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat'])).'" OR Category2="'.mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat2'])).'"';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! the thing that was missing was : <a href="?cat=scinece&cat2=science">Science</a> and do this for every category <a href="?cat=nature&cat2=nature">Nature</a> etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You can modified the code as below:

```
<?php 
$subQ = ''; 
if(isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat']!=''){
$subQ = ' WHERE Category="'.mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat'])).'"';}   
if(isset($_GET['cat2']) && $_GET['cat2']!=''){
$subQ .= ' and Category2="'.mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['cat2'])).'"';} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input ! the thing that was missing was : <a href="?cat=scinece&cat2=science">Science</a> and do this for every category <a href="?cat=nature&cat2=nature">Nature</a> etc etc

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this right you're looking to create a many-to-many relationship between categories and documentaries.  To do this the category should no longer be a field in the `documentary` table (I'm assuming that's what it's called).  Instead you will create two new tables, a `category` table that contains two fields, a category id and a name.  The second table will be a `documentary_to_category` table with two fields, a documentary id and a category id.  The documentary id and the category id are both foreign keys to documentary.id and category.id respectively.

Now you would need to rewrite your query to something like the following:

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($_GET['category'] as $categoryId) {
    if (ctype_digit($categoryId)) {
        $categories[] = $categoryId;
    }
}

$sql = 'SELECT d.id, d.name, category_id
        FROM documentary d
        JOIN documentary_to_category dtc
            ON dtc.documentary_id = d.id
        WHERE dtc.category_id IN(' . implode(',', $categories) . ')
        GROUP BY d.id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = ' . count($categories);
```

Now your links would look something like this:

```
<a href="?category[]=1&category[]=2">Nature and Science</a>
```

below I've included graphical representations of the two new tables:

```
-----------------------------------------
|            category                    |
------------------------------------------
|  id   |           name                 |
------------------------------------------
|  1    |         Science                |
|  2    |         Nature                 |
|  3    |         ...                    |
------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------
|      documentary_to_category          |
-----------------------------------------
|   documentary_id   |    category_id   |
-----------------------------------------
|      1             |         1        |
|      1             |         2        |
|      2             |         1        |
|      2             |         3        |
|      ...           |       ...        |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you Crashspeeder ! the thing that was missing was : <a href="?cat=scinece&cat2=science">Science</a> and do this for every category <a href="?cat=nature&cat2=nature">Nature</a> etc etc

Comment: Just be careful with variables and database fields that end with numbers.  Normally this is a sign of something that is unsustainable and doesn't scale.